# How can I load (change) image src with AMP-Carousel? (AMP For Email)

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

I'm trying to carousel display three images at a time (type="carousel"), where each image represents a category, where the user can click on an image in the carousel to load/display additional information(text and image) on that category underneath the carousel. From my initial exploration of the documentation, I was unable to find an example of this. It seems this isn't possible with type="carousel". Would appreciate any confirmation of this or if I'm wrong with my assumption here.

WORKAROUND:
I did discover if I use type="slides" instead (carousel displays one image at a time) with the AMP-Bind component, I can use the "on" event to change/update content elsewhere in the email each time the prev/next button is pressed. Not perfect, but a reasonable alternative approach from the original idea.

```
<amp-carousel
   type="slides"
   on="slideChange:AMP.setState({ currentAdventure: event.index} )">
```

The Amp for Email documentation page for amp-bind shows an example (A slightly more complex example) of binding [src] to amp-img to change an image source path:

```
<amp-state id="myAnimals">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "dog": {
        "imageUrl": "/img/dog.jpg",
        "style": "greenBackground"
      }
...
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>

<amp-img width="300" height="200" src="/img/dog.jpg"
    [src]="myAnimals[currentAnimal].imageUrl">
</amp-img>
```

AMP FOR EMAIL PLAYGROUND:
So far so good I thought. It appears I can update both text and an image source path. While I can update text, The Amp For Email validator flagged  the use of [src] in the amp-img tag and thus failed to change the image.  :-(

I'm guessing this is probably for security reasons implemented sometime afterwards.

SOLUTIONS?
Is there another way to update an image source path or is this simply not allowable under any circumstance? Is AMP-list a possible solution? If so, not sure how to implement with my code snippets below (Jason, Carousel, and content block to update)

My apologies for such a lengthy explanation and appreciate any insights. Thank you for sharing your time and knowledge.

```
<amp-state id="myState">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "adventure": [
         {
          "name": "Category 1 copy...",
          "description": "Trip 1 | Trip 2 | Trip 3 | Trip 4,
          "image": "https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/images/image1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "name": "Category 2 copy...",
          "description": "Trip 5 | Trip 6 | Trip 7 | Trip 8",
          "image": "https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/images/image2.jpg"
        },
        {
          "name": "Category 3 copy...",
          "description": "Trip 9 | Trip 10 | Trip 11 | Trip 12",
          "image": "https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/images/image3.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>



<amp-carousel
    width="543"
    height="150"
    type="slides"
    on="slideChange:AMP.setState({ currentAdventure: event.index} )">

    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/images/image1.jpg" 
        width="175"
        height="150"></amp-img>
    ....

</amp-carousel>



<div class="center">
<h1>
<span [text]="myState.adventure[currentAdventure].name">Category 1 copy..."</span>
</h1>
<p class="center" [text]="myState.adventure[currentAdventure].description">Trip 1 | Trip 2 | Trip 3 | Trip 4</p>
<amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/images/image1.jpg" 
        width="175"
        height="150"
        [src]="myState.adventure[currentAdventure].image"></amp-img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

AMP for Email doesn't support binding to `[src]` or `[href]` (this is mentioned in [AMP for Email Supported Components](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/email-spec/amp-email-components/?format=email)).

Instead, what you can do here is simply have all the images (and other content) for each slide part of your document and then use the `[hidden]` binding to hide the ones that are not related to the current slide, like this:

```
<amp-state id="currentAdventure">
  <script type="application/json">
    0
  </script>
</amp-state>

<amp-carousel
  width="543"
  height="150"
  type="slides"
  on="slideChange:AMP.setState({ currentAdventure: event.index} )">

  <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/images/image1.jpg" 
    width="175"
    height="150"></amp-img>

  ....

</amp-carousel>


<div class="center">
  <div [hidden]="currentAdventure != 0">
    <h1>
      <span>Category 1 copy..."</span>
    </h1>
    <p class="center">Trip 1 | Trip 2 | Trip 3 | Trip 4</p>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/images/image1.jpg" width="175" height="150"></amp-img>
  </div>
  <div hidden [hidden]="currentAdventure != 1">
    <h1>
      <span>Category 2 copy...</span>
    </h1>
    <p class="center">Trip 5 | Trip 6 | Trip 7 | Trip 8</p>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/images/image2.jpg" width="175" height="150"></amp-img>
  </div>
  <div hidden [hidden]="currentAdventure != 2">
    <h1>
      <span>Category 3 copy...</span>
    </h1>
    <p class="center">Trip 9 | Trip 10 | Trip 11 | Trip 12</p>
    <amp-img src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/images/image3.jpg" width="175" height="150"></amp-img>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way, you only need to keep the slide index in the state and use it to hide the parts of the page that aren't relevant.